# Javascript - Simulate Keyboard Input into AngularJS Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm working on a Chrome Extension that executes a content script in pure Javascript where I could simulate keypresses into Inputs.

However the site I'm trying to simulate keypresses into is running `AngularJS`.

### The Form

Here's the HTML code of the form and the input. Note the `ng-untouched`, `ng-pristine`, `ng-valid` classes on the elements.

```
<form _ngcontent-ysv-c110="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <esw-address _ngcontent-ysv-c110="">
       <esw-address-my _nghost-ysv-c130="">
          <div _ngcontent-ysv-c130="" class="address-form ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">

             <esw-input _ngcontent-ysv-c130="" type="text" eswtrim="" class="address-form__firstName ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" _nghost-ysv-c109="" maxlength="60">
                
                <!-- THIS INPUT -->
                <input _ngcontent-ysv-c109="" triggers="manual" class="textInput ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required="" maxlength="60">
             
            </esw-input>

          </div>
       </esw-address-my>
    </esw-address>
    <button _ngcontent-ysv-c110="" type="button" translate="" class="button-continue">Save Continue</button>
 </form>
```

### The Code I'm Using

Currently the way I try to simulate keypresses into this input is by running the following code:

```
var firstNameV = "Alex";
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
firstName.focus();
var firstNameV = addressObj['firstName'];
for (let i = 0; i < firstNameV.length; i++) {
    var char = firstNameV[i];
    firstName.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': char }));
    firstName.value += char;
    firstName.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { 'key': char }));
    await sleep(10);
}
```

### Problem

However when I go ahead and submit the form, the fields light up red as the elements did not change from `ng-untouched` to `ng-touched` or `ng-pristine` to `ng-dirty`.

So my question, is there a way to properly simulate typing into an AngularJS input in order to trigger the 'touched' event and pass form validation so I could submit the form?

Also I'd like to add that I do not have access to the `angular` / `$scope` variables in Javascript. Thus, I'm not sure what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution helped me 99% of time.
Mostly  the  change event needs to be triggered.

**EDIT:** For a better example please provide a stackblitz example.
Without knowing your Website I cant reproduce it and only can guess.

```js
$("#testButton").on("click", function (e) {
fillField('testInput', "Stackoverflow rocks!", false)
})


function fillField(id, value, select) {
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element) {
    element.focus();
    if (!select && element.value.length == 0) {
      simulateTyping(element, value, 0);
    } else {
      let event = new Event("change");
      element.value = value;
      element.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    element.blur();
  }
}


function simulateTyping(element, value, i) {
  if (i < value.length) {
    element.value += value.charAt(i);
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    setTimeout(() => {
      i++;
      simulateTyping(element, value, i);
    }, 20);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
}

.form {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.email-form {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.button {
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 9px 12px;
    color: #333333;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body class="body">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="email-form"><input type="text" id="testInput" class="input"><a href="#" id="testButton" class="button">GO</a></form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. However this did not solve my issue. I tried both `fillField('firstName', "Bob", false)` and `fillField('firstName', "Bob", true)`. The site i'm trying this on is hidden behind a Login. Essentially it's `Nike.com`. Would you still like the link to the site to give it a try?

Comment: The more information the better :) I am from the same scene

Comment: Well in that case ^-^ https://gs.nike.com/?checkoutId=fa7aec4e-fb72-8534-ef32-c172197c9560&launchId=2ca7c0dc-afb1-356a-ab21-405170f601cd&skuId=3f348e99-d10a-55ae-8f0a-25246b52b430&country=MY&locale=en-GB&appId=com.nike.commerce.snkrs.web&returnUrl=https:%2F%2Fwww.nike.com%2Fmy%2Flaunch%2Ft%2Fair-jordan-1-shoes%2F After login, add a new address, you should see the form appear.